# Add 1 year to a month year in a cell

Tags: excel, date

I have data I imported into excel that only uses month and year for a date ( 02/23). I need to add 1 year and place in a cell that is conditionally formatted to turn red once that month equals current month of current year. Can’t find anyway to work without using day as well. Thank you for looking.

I have not been able to find any way to work with month year only

Comment: is your data strings, or date serial numbers formatted to display `mm/yy`?

Answer (score 1):

If `A1` has your date (02/23) then the following formula will add one year:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```

Then apply conditional formatting

[image: Excel screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is another option ...

```
=EDATE(A1, 12)
```

Something to note, if the **29th of Feb, 2016** is used as a reference date, `EDATE` will return **28th of Feb, 2017** and the the `DATE` function (`=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))`) will return the **1st of March, 2017** ... you need to decide which is correct for your scenario.

[image: Dates Comparison]